# How can I generate an XML or text file from certain text in a Word doc

Tags: excel, xml, ms-word, xsd, export-to-xml

So my issue is, as part of my job I have to complete in regular reports on word which are formatted in tables. I then have to go online and fill in an online form with all the information from the report. The form does accept XML file uploads to fill in the report so I have been trying to find a way to convert the information entered on the report into an XML file.

I've tried converting the word document to XML directly but alot of extra information is captured (styling etc) so the online portal doesn't accept the file.

I've tried adding the data to excel and exporting that as an XML but excel can't export it.

I was thinking if there was a way to read my document and write to a plain text document based off what sections of the table had been filled in?

Here is an example of the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Declaration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://oris.ctif-cfi.be/Declaration.xsd">
    <AuthorizedPerson>
        <AuthorizedPersonId>TEST</AuthorizedPersonId>
        <Abbreviation>TEST</Abbreviation>
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </AuthorizedPerson>
    <Disclosure>
        <ExternalReference>TESTINGREF</ExternalReference>
        <DisclosureType>2</DisclosureType>
        <Urgency>Urgent</Urgency>
        <InternalReference xsi:nil="true" />
        <ReferenceDossier>DVTESTCOMPLE</ReferenceDossier>
        <DeclarationDate>1900-01-01</DeclarationDate>
        <SessionId xsi:nil="true" />
    </Disclosure>
    <Subject>
        <SubjectType>Physical</SubjectType>
        <PhysicalSubject>
            <Name>TestLast1</Name>
            <FirstName>TestFirst1</FirstName>
            <BirthDate>2000-01-01</BirthDate>
            <BirthPlace>Kumasi</BirthPlace>
            <BirthCountry>BE</BirthCountry>
            <NationalRegister>00000000</NationalRegister>
            <Activity />
            <Nationality>MN</Nationality>
            <Location>
                <Address>
                    <Street>TestStreet1</Street>
                    <Number>23</Number>
                </Address>
                <ZipCode>18000</ZipCode>
                <City>TestCity1</City>
                <Country>AO</Country>
            </Location>
            <Document>
                <DocumentType>3</DocumentType>
                <DocumentDescription>Passport</DocumentDescription>
                <Number>1234567890</Number>
                <ValidUntil>2020-12-12</ValidUntil>
                <Country>AM</Country>
            </Document>
        </PhysicalSubject>
    </Subject>
    <Subject>
        <SubjectType>Physical</SubjectType>
        <PhysicalSubject>
            <Name>TestLast2</Name>
            <FirstName>TestFirst2</FirstName>
            <BirthDate>1960-01-09</BirthDate>
            <BirthPlace />
            <BirthCountry>n/a</BirthCountry>
            <NationalRegister>0000000000</NationalRegister>
            <Activity />
            <Nationality>ZM</Nationality>
            <Location>
                <Address>
                    <Street>TEST ADDRESS2</Street>
                    <Number>11</Number>
                </Address>
                <ZipCode>16000</ZipCode>
                <City>TESTCITY</City>
                <Country>LT</Country>
            </Location>
        </PhysicalSubject>
    </Subject>
    <TransactionDescription>
        <ZipCodeBranch>0000</ZipCodeBranch>
        <ZipCodeOperation />
        <Description>TEST DESCRIPTION OF FACTS</Description>
    </TransactionDescription>
    <Indications>
        <Art10bis>false</Art10bis>
        <Description>TEST INDICATIONS</Description>
    </Indications>
    <Investigation>
        <Known>false</Known>
        <ReferenceFile />
        <IdentificationService />
        <AnalystName />
        <GeneralComment />
    </Investigation>
    <GeneralComments>
        <GeneralComment>TEST GENERAL COMMENTS</GeneralComment>
    </GeneralComments>
</Declaration>
```

Comment: You could probably build a program that reads the document and creates XML yes, as long as the documents always has the same structure.  However it would probably be a rather fragile solution, and any change in the Document structure would cause it to break.  Is there no option to capture the information at source and generate the XML and Word Document at that point?

Comment: Unfortunately the structure is not the same all the time, there can be an unlimited number of Subjects, also depending on the disclosure type selected, the ReferenceDossier field will/won't appear.

Unfortunately not, you can only save your current report on the online system as XML and then upload it to continue filing. So I am basically attempting to "sideload" XMLs through the upload rather than filling in the form with the data from the report I wrote in Word. If I were to make a program, which language do you think would be most suitable?

Comment: So can't you use the online system to enter all the information, then export XML, and then have something that takes that XML and creates your Word Report?   There are many programming languages that you can achieve this with.  Are you familiar with any?  Maybe you need to talk to the people you work for and suggest this as a project and they will do the analysis, design and will chose their preferred programming language.